# Product Items with Individual Price in WordPress Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i want the product items to be added withing the product within the WordPress woo-commerce in cart page. Can you please guide me is it possible to do this. How can i achieve this? Is there any wordpress/woo-commerce plugin that can do this? I have searched allot but didn't find anything helpful.

Here is what i actually want. My main product in the form of ticket and then withing that product three product items with different prices each. On the left side of the image is my main product and on the right side these are the products items that i want the users to add them in their product.

[image]

Comment: Did you try reading the docs for Woocommerce? https://docs.woothemes.com/document/variable-product/

Comment: Yes i do read them in fact i applied that but it give me a drop-down option instead of list of items.

Comment: This is going to sound like self-promotion, but have you considered [Mix and match products](http://www.woothemes.com/products/woocommerce-mix-and-match-products)?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you're wanting is a product that is composed of other products.  In general eCommerce business models, this is referred to as a product bundle.  WooCommerce offers an extension for this functionality.  https://docs.woothemes.com/document/bundles/